# Passing multiple parameters of same column to SQL Server select SP

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a string value in the web.config — for example 2 guids separated by a `","`.  I need to query the database dynamically (i.e i have no idea how many values could be separated by a comma in the web.config) and run a select statement on the table passing these values and getting all that is relevant for example:

```
select * from tablename where columnname = string1 string2 string3 etc etc
```

some strings may only contain 1 guid some may contain 10

Answer (score 4):

Check out Erland Sommarskogs excellent post on this topic:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

SQL Server 2008 would also offer [table-valued parameters](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) in addition to these ways of passing multiple values to the procedure.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

You want an "IN" condition.  If you *really* trust your web.config and can require the configured elements are also encased in quotes, you can just put it directly into the sql statement:

```
select * from tablename where columnname IN ( "web.config value here" )
```

But be warned that dynamic sql like this is *very* dangerous.  On the other hand, passing them in safely can be [tricky](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).

Comment: i have never seen this approach, could get messy but interesting.

Answer (score 1):

this is based on Erland Sommarskogs article:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Before you use my function, you need to set up a "helper" table, you only need to do this one time per database:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers
(Number int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
DECLARE @x int
SET @x=0
WHILE @x<8000
BEGIN
    SET @x=@x+1
    INSERT INTO Numbers VALUES (@x)
END
```

use this function to split your string, which does not loop and is very fast:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ListToTable]
(
     @SplitOn              char(1)              --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
    ,@List                 varchar(8000)        --REQUIRED, the list to split apart
)
RETURNS
@ParsedList table
(
    ListValue varchar(500)
)
AS
BEGIN

/**
Takes the given @List string and splits it apart based on the given @SplitOn character.
A table is returned, one row per split item, with a column name "ListValue".
This function workes for fixed or variable lenght items.
Empty and null items will not be included in the results set.


Returns a table, one row per item in the list, with a column name "ListValue"

EXAMPLE:
----------
SELECT * FROM dbo.FN_ListToTable(',','1,12,123,1234,54321,6,A,*,|||,,,,B')

    returns:
        ListValue  
        -----------
        1
        12
        123
        1234
        54321
        6
        A
        *
        |||
        B

        (10 row(s) affected)

**/



----------------
--SINGLE QUERY-- --this will not return empty rows
----------------
INSERT INTO @ParsedList
        (ListValue)
    SELECT
        ListValue
        FROM (SELECT
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
                  FROM (
                           SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS List2
                       ) AS dt
                      INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
                  WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = @SplitOn
             ) dt2
        WHERE ListValue IS NOT NULL AND ListValue!=''



RETURN

END --Function FN_ListToTable
```

you can use this function as a table in a join, which will be fast and use the index:

```
SELECT
    Col1, COl2, Col3...
    FROM  YourTable
        INNER JOIN FN_ListToTable(',',@YourString) s ON  YourTable.ID = s.ListValue
```

you can split strings or numbers, here are some string examples:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000)
SET @YourString='monkey,elephant,dog,bear,zebra'
select * from FN_ListToTable(',',@YourString)

SET @YourString='two words,three words here,four words right here,five is the magic number,six words is even more fun'
select * from FN_ListToTable(',',@YourString)


SET @YourString='Doe, Jane; Smith, Joe; Public, John Q.'
select * from FN_ListToTable(';',@YourString)
```

Comment: can you help, i am using string and not numbers and cannot get your approach to work

Comment: Can you please explain a helper table

Comment: the helper table is basically a table named Numbers that contains a column "Number", with a row for each number from 1 to 8000 or more.  What is your problem with the helper table?  It is used by the function to find the split character, the inner derived table basically returns a row for each character that contains a split character (no looping involved).  The outer derived table uses those rows to actually split apart the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to send multiple parameters, only one string

A posibility is to parse that string into an SQL stored procedure and build a dynamic query

Another posibility is to insert the '' characters at every , and use to code below

```
'aaa','bbb','ccc'

myTable
------------
ID  Name

1   eee
2   aaa
3   ggg
4   hhh
5   bbb


declare @stmt nvarchar(1000)
set @stmt = 'select * from myTable where Name in (''aaa'',''bbb'',''ccc'')'
exec spexecute_sql @stmt
```

Comment: i am passing my value in dynamically @myString and it always returns 0 results, can you help